# Is there an equivalent of 'lost in translation' but for writing? As in all the subtle information we lose when texting instead of talking face to face

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

When we text instead of talking face-to-face, we lose important information such as body language, tone, periods of silence, facial expressions, etc... This is why something that was a positive or joking comment in real life could sound rude when texting.

Is there an expression for this? Lost in textualization would make sense, but it sounds unnatural to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Translation" is applicable to written words as well as spoken words. There is no reason not to use "Lost in translation" when writing.

If you are talking about the information you lose when communicating in writing rather than face to face, that is called "non-verbal information", also called "non-verbal cues", "non verbal context" etc.

> "When communicating in writing, we lack the non-verbal information that provides additional understanding and context".